# Lorentz transformation sign convention confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, conventions

I am really confused with expressions under Lorentz transformation. I will try to showcase my confusion  via an easy and very popular example:

If we have two inertial systems $S$ and $S'$, and $S'$ is moving relative to S with velocity $v$.
A point charge is in the origin of $S'$. Initially at $t=t'=0$ their origins are at the same point.

In $S'$:

We only have electric field: $\vec E'= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\vec r'}{|\vec r'|^3}$

There is no magnetic field: $\vec B'=0$

We want to know the electric field and magnetic field at point $P=(0,b,0)$.

This point is in $S$ system as $\vec P=(0,b,0)$.

This point is in $S'$ system as $\vec P'=(x',b,0)$. Performing Lorentz transformation of the kind $x'=\gamma(x -vt)$. We know that $x=0$, therefore $x'=-v\gamma t$. Then $\vec P'=(-v\gamma t,b,0)$. I consider that these are the coordinates of point $\vec P'$ observed by someone in the system $S'$, but via the coordinates of the same point $\vec P$ observed by someone in the rest frame.

But we can also express the coordinates of $\vec P'=(-vt',b,0)$. Here the coordinates are directly  related to the frame at motion, and no Lorentz transformation takes place.

Anyway, we perform Lorentz transformations etc and for the x component of the Electric field we have:

$$E_x=E_x'=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{-vt'}{(b^2 + v^2t'^2)^{\frac 32 }}=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{-v\gamma t}{(b^2 + \gamma^2v^2t^2)^{\frac 32 }}$$

Both of the above expressions are related to $E_x'$.

When the observer is in the rest frame of the particle and no LT takes place, the expression for the electric field at $\vec P'$ is:

$$E_x'=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{-vt'}{(b^2 + v^2t'^2)^{\frac 32 }}$$

Now if we want to express the x-component of the electric field, but by utilizing the coordinates from the rest frame, we would get:

$$E_x'=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{-v\gamma t}{(b^2 + \gamma^2v^2t^2)^{\frac 32 }}$$

But if I want to know the expression of the x-component, described by an observer at the rest frame $S$, while taking into consideration the coordinates from the frame at motion $S'$, we need to perform the following LT: $x=\gamma(x'+vt)$ and because $x'=-vt$, I would get $x=0$, which is correct because in the rest frame the point where we want to find the electric field is $\vec P(0,b,0)$ which has a $0$ for the x component. As a result $E_x=0$. But this is not possible since $E_x=E_x'$ for this case.

So what exactly I am not understanding here?

Comment: No, I am talking about the transformations, so it's lorentz

Comment: Yes, I did edit the correct name

Answer (score 0):

The electric field in $S'$ is
$$ {\bf E}' = \frac{k}{(x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2)^{3/2}} (x'{\bf i} + y'{\bf j} + z'{\bf k}) \, $$
using conventional notation and Cartesian coordinates.

To transform this into another frame of reference we use
$$ {\bf E} = {\bf E'_{\parallel}} + \gamma({\bf E_{\perp}} - {\bf v} \times {\bf B'})\ ,                   $$
where the subscripts represent the components of the E-field on $S'$ that are parallel or perpendicular to the velocity difference between $S$ and $S'$, which is labelled as ${\bf v}$. In this case ${\bf v} = v{\bf i}$ and ${\bf B'}=0$ (because there are no currents in this frame).

Hence
$${\bf E} = \frac{k}{(x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2)^{3/2}}\left( x'{\bf i} + \gamma(y'{\bf j} + z'{\bf k})\right) $$
Thus
$$ E_x = \frac{kx'}{(x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2)^{3/2}}$$
in the coordinate system of $S'$.
In $S'$ the point $P$ is at $(-vt', b, 0)$, so
$$ E_x(P) = \frac{-kvt'}{(v^2 t'^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}$$

Then, $x' = \gamma(x-vt)$, $y'=y$ and $z'=z$, so
$${\bf E} = \frac{k}{(\gamma^2(x-vt)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}\left( \gamma(x-vt){\bf i} + \gamma(y{\bf j} + z{\bf k})\right) $$
and
$$E_x = \frac{\gamma k (x-vt)}{(\gamma^2(x-vt)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} $$
Substitute $x=0$, $y=b$, $z=0$ for your answer.
$$E_x(P) = \frac{-\gamma kvt}{(\gamma^2 v^2 t^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}\ .$$

Are these results the same? Well transform back with $t = \gamma (t' + vx'/c^2) = \gamma (t' - v^2t'/c^2) = t'/\gamma$ and you see that they are.

I don't understand where you get $x'=-vt$ in the last paragraph and you don't appear to have used the Lorentz transform for $t = f(t',x')$.

Comment: I have two questions: You say $\vec B=0$. Which I agree. The reason why I consider it zero is because in the frame of reference in which the particle appears as if it is not moving, in other words in the rest frame of the point charge, there is no magnetic field since the charge ain't moving. Is this the reason why you also consider it zero, or because you derivative it from your initial equation ?.

Comment: Regarding the question where i got $x'=-vt'$. The rest frame of the particle I denote everything with the prime symbol. In other words an event observed in the rest frame of the particle has the spacetime coordinates: (t',x',y',z'). Now the Point P, initially is for both systems at (0,b,0). Once the particle moves, the point P appears to the rest frame of the particles, as it is going in the opposite direction. If the particle is moving in the pos. x direction, the point  P is moving in the opposite, and for a given time $t'$ it has the x coordinate $x'=-vt'$

Comment: Your last paragraph says $x' = -vt$. @imbAF Anyway, I find no discrepancies or problems.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with EM problems it is best to use the full tensor based approach. Although the notation is a bit confusing at first, the coordinate transformations are essentially built-in to the framework. The EM field tensor is given by $$F^{\mu \nu }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
 E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
 E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
 E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In your case with a point charge at the origin in the primed frame we have: $$F^{\mu' \nu' }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -\frac{k q x'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{k q y'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} &
   -\frac{k q z'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q x'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{k q y'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{k q z'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow  \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{k q t' v}{\left(b^2+t'^2 v^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{b k q}{\left(b^2+t'^2 v^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{k q t' v}{\left(b^2+t'^2 v^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{b k q}{\left(b^2+t'^2 v^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ where $k=1/(4\pi \epsilon_0)$ and $q=1$ in your setup. Here the arrow represents evaluating the field on the worldline $(t,0,b,0)=(t',- vt',b,0)$. Note that there is no time dependence in the field itself, but by evaluating it on a specific worldline you introduce a time dependence.

Now, when transforming, I generally prefer to transform the full tensor field first and then specialize to a given point, just to be safe. So if we transform the full tensor then we get $$ F^{\mu \nu }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{k q (t v-x) \gamma }{\left(\left(\gamma ^2-1\right) t^2-2 v x \gamma ^2 t+y^2+z^2+x^2 \gamma
   ^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{k q y \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{k q z
   \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q (x-t v) \gamma }{\left(\left(\gamma ^2-1\right) t^2-2 v x \gamma ^2 t+y^2+z^2+x^2 \gamma
   ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & -\frac{k q v y \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{k
   q v z \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q y \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{k q v y \gamma
   }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{k q z \gamma }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{k q v z \gamma
   }{\left(y^2+z^2+(x-t v)^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ This specifies the whole EM field tensor throughout spacetime in the primed frame. Note that the field is a function of $t$, as expected. Now, we specialize and evaluate the field on the worldline $(t,0, b,0)$ to get $$F^{\mu \nu } \rightarrow \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{k q t v \gamma }{\left(b^2+t^2 \left(\gamma ^2-1\right)\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{b k q \gamma
   }{\left(b^2+t^2 v^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 \\
 -\frac{k q t v \gamma }{\left(b^2+t^2 \left(\gamma ^2-1\right)\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & -\frac{b k q v \gamma
   }{\left(b^2+t^2 v^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{b k q \gamma }{\left(b^2+t^2 v^2 \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{b k q v \gamma }{\left(b^2+t^2 v^2
   \gamma ^2\right)^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is usually best to work the long way, meaning transform the full field and then evaluate it along whatever worldline you wish, rather than evaluating it along the worldline and then transforming. I have not checked, for this problem whether the order makes a difference, but I always opt for the cautious approach.

Comment: Why is it $x' -t'v$? And not $x'+v't$? And one more thing. Can you explain to me how to understand this: $x=x'-t'v$.I know that  is the result of a LT and that is it. The goal the point?

Comment: @imbAF oops, it looks like I got the primes and unprimes reversed. Just replace all of my primes with your unprimes and all of my v with -v. I will try to update later

Comment: Actually, I also got the frame where the worldline is at rest backwards that will take more rewriting

Comment: I have fixed the problem and undeleted it.